# Add installer to Windows service project

Tags: c#, installation

In my solution i have Winforms, WCF library and Windows service
Currently i am install my `WCF service` manually using `InstallUtil` and follow [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_YUcBxc5xM) video didn't solve my problem.
How can i do it ? (i only want installer for my service)

BTW i am using Visual studio 2013

Comment: If some one can create a basic service + installer project on github that would be awesome. Just saying. (Note to self: Go and work out how to do that and put it up myself.)